# Standardize word VBA usage within the team

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a team of 10 persons who work on Word documents, they format per defined guidelines. We have created a macro that corrects the font, size and formatting.

How can I ensure that nobody can change/replace or delete this macro from their system? In case this happens I should get an alert.

Can something be done at the system or program level?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that no-one changes it, you can set a password on the macro. [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233396) should get you there. But that won't help with notifying you.

Comment: But even though it is protected with password, but any user might replace it with another macro with same name or delete this. How this can be avoided?